# Publish WCF Service app on IIS Express using Web Deployment

Tags: .net, wcf, web-deployment, iis-express

I want to publish WCF Service Application created in Visual Studio 2010 on IIS Express.

So I'm using Project -> Publish -> Web Deploy:

```
Service URL: http://localhost
Site/application: wcf
```

But ran into some miss-understanding:

- Web Deployment requires a virtual directory, it doesn't want to publish in the site root
- IIS Express [doesn't support](http://forums.asp.net/p/1586631/4010126.aspx) virtual directories

How can I accomplish the task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fist of all, you need to specify the correct Service URL, i.e. `http://server/MsDeployAgentService`

Answer (score 1):

You can add a virtual directory via a command line using appcmd:

```
appcmd add vdir /app.name:<site_name>/ /path:/<virtual_directory> /physicalPath:<physical_location>
```

See [here](http://forums.iis.net/t/1170326.aspx)

Comment: How to create vdir `wcf` on site `WcfService1` in `c:\WcfService1`?

Comment: If you already have site named WcfService1 the command is: `appcmd add vdir /app.name:WcfService1/ /path:/wcf /physicalPath:c:\WcfService1`

Comment: I tried the same and got: `ERROR ( message:Cannot find APP object with identifier "WcfService1/". )`

Comment: It means that the site with name WcfService1 does not exists

Comment: Are you sure you need to install under WcfService1 site. To install in default site you can use the following command: `vdir /app.name:"Default Web Site"/ /path:/wcf /physicalPath:c:\WcfService1`. To Create a new site you can use: `appcmd add site /name:WcfService1 /id:2 /physicalPath:C:\WcfService1 /bindings:http/*:8080` (this site will listen to port 8080

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to specify the destination of your web site/application in site properties -> Package/Publish Web.
In the field "IIS Web Site/application name to use on the destination server" put the site name. There, by default, the application is specified as a virtual directory but it does not have to be. You can just put the name of your site there, without the "/" and then it will deploy to the root of the site, not a virtual (sub-)directory. See screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

IIS Express does support virtual directories. Using appcmd command provided by 'Eugene' should work.