# How to publish WCF Service using IIS Express?

Tags: wcf, windows-7, iis-express

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Publish WCF Service app on IIS Express using Web Deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5704166/publish-wcf-service-app-on-iis-express-using-web-deployment)

I have Windows 7 Home basic Operating System and I want to publish WCF Service on it. As Windows7 Home Basic is not supporting IIS I have downloaded IIS Express from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1038) and installed it. Now can any one guide me how to publish WCF Service using IIS Express?
Thanks

Comment: I guess the hosting process in IIS Express should be similar to hosting in IIS 7. You can find some comparision of IIS Express with IIS 7 here : http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/868/iis-express-overview/

Comment: Rajesh, Thanks for the link. I was not clear with IIS Express and Microsoft WebMatrix. But now I am. Now I will install Webmatrix and and try to publish WCF Service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StackOverflow contains a few same posts - [Problem hosting WCF service in IIS Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489062/problem-hosting-wcf-service-in-iis-express) and [Publish WCF Service app on IIS Express using Web Deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5704166/publish-wcf-service-app-on-iis-express-using-web-deployment) and you can check this article - [Using IIS Express to Secure Silverlight and WCF Applications](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2011/05/21/using-iis-express-to-secure-silverlight-and-wcf-applications.aspx)